# Read asset file in non Activity Class android

Tags: java, android

I have A asset file on my Project the file containt html code now i want to Get those code by String on Bellow code so Please Help me
How i Read asset file in String on Bellow code

```
public class StartPage {

      final String FILENAME = data();

    private static final String HEAD_1 = "<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">"
            + "<head>"
            + "<meta content=\"en-us\" http-equiv=\"Content-Language\" />"
            + "<meta content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" />"
            + "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\">"
            + "<title>";


    @NonNull
    public static File getStartPageFile(@NonNull Application application) {
        return new File(application.getFilesDir(), FILENAME);
    }

    @NonNull private final String mTitle;

    @Inject Application mApp;
    @Inject SearchEngineProvider mSearchEngineProvider;

    public StartPage() {
        BrowserApp.getAppComponent().inject(this);
        mTitle = mApp.getString(R.string.home);
    }

    @NonNull
    public Single<String> getHomepage() {
        return Single.create(new SingleAction<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(@NonNull SingleSubscriber<String> subscriber) {

                StringBuilder homepageBuilder = new StringBuilder(HEAD_1 + mTitle );

                BaseSearchEngine currentSearchEngine = mSearchEngineProvider.getCurrentSearchEngine();

                String icon = currentSearchEngine.getIconUrl();
                String searchUrl = currentSearchEngine.getQueryUrl();

                homepageBuilder.append(icon);

                homepageBuilder.append(searchUrl);


                File homepage = getStartPageFile(mApp);
                FileWriter hWriter = null;
                try {
                    //noinspection IOResourceOpenedButNotSafelyClosed
                    hWriter = new FileWriter(homepage, false);
                    hWriter.write(homepageBuilder.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Utils.close(hWriter);
                }

                subscriber.onItem(Constants.FILE + homepage);

            }
        });
     private String data(){
        InputStream inputStream = getAsseet().openRawResource(R.raw.database);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int i;
        try {
            i = inputStream.read();
            while (i != -1)
            {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
                i = inputStream.read();
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
    }
 }

}
```

I try here to read asset file but here give  error(can not Resolve method getAsset()  )so please help me by writing code
Thanks
Osman

Comment: Show the error or stacktraces you get in the body of the question.

Comment: i can not get any soluation for insert code here but same code when insert activity class it work fine

Comment: No one wants to debug your code for you. If you have a specific question about this code you need to make that clear, and provide relevant results like errors or stacktraces.

Comment: I fully Update My Code Please see now

Answer (score 2):

`getAssets()` is a method of class `Context`. In Activity, you can call just `getAssets()` because it is treated as `this.getAssets()`, and Activity is a sub class of `Context`. That's why you can call it in `Activty`. Since your class is not a subclass of a `Context`, you can't call `getAssets()` or `this.getAssets()` in your class, since there is no such method.

So now you have to get some `Context` to be able to call `getAssets()`. You have an instance of the `Application mApp;`, which is a subclass of `Context` as well as `Activty`. So you can call `mApp.getAssets()`

Comment: Please write full Code for Help me

Comment: @OsmanGani, sorry, but why don't you write code? Why should I write it? It is your code in the end...

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code. Hope this will work!

```
String convertedString = loadJSONFromAsset(context,"myfile.html");
Log.d("converstion" ,"converted string" + convertedString ); // it will print the entire file as string.

public String loadJSONFromAsset(Context context,String fileName) {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("foldername/" + fileName);
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for help here a error  String convertedString = loadJSONFromAsset(context,"myfile.html"); Cant Resolove Symbol context

Comment: you need to pass your activity or fragment context. like getApplicationContext() or getActivity();

Comment: Please See my code again  here it non Activity Class it How use Context Here

Comment: Anyway you will call this method from any activity or fragment correct?

Comment: Or else try to use application context here.

Comment: Well, given this is a regular class, just pass the app context to the constructor.